# Selective DNS server usage

Tags: linux, windows, networking, dns

I'm mainly working on the road, connected via a VPN provided by the employer.
For a handful of services, I depend on the companies internal DNS server, meaning that I need to use the DNS server via the VPN to use some services.

For the sake of simplicity, lets say that I need to access `service-one.local` and `service-two.lab`. Until now I've always just used the DNS server via the VPN, but that makes general browsing very slow as all DNS requests have to go to the internal DNS server.

I also can't just use a public DNS server, as that would leak private server/service names (e.g. `service-one.local`).

Is there a way to selectively configure DNS servers?

I'd like to define two DNS servers, the internal one - accessible via the VPN and a public one.

The first should only be used for defined domains and the public one should be used for anything else, to speed up requests. I could just use the public DNS server and use hosts entries for the internal services - but that would be very static.

The target operating systems are Windows 10 and Ubuntu LTS.

Comment: Do you really *need* to use the internal DNS server? You could just add the hosts to the `hosts` file.

Comment: @DanielB As described in the question - yes, I could add the hosts to the `hosts` file, but that would make the whole system very static and prone to errors on changes.